# Big-Oh notation for code fragment

Tags: code-analysis, big-o

I am lost on these code fragments and finding a hard time to find any other similar examples.

```
//Code fragment 1  
sum = 0;  
for(i = 0;i < n; i++)  
 for(J=1;j<i*i;J++)    
   for(K=0;k<j;k++)
    sum++;
```

I'm guessing it is O(n^4) for fragment 1.

```
//Code fragment 2
sum = 0;
for( 1; i < n; i++ )
 for (j =1;,j < i * i; j++)
  if( j % i == 0 )
   for( k = 0; k < j; k++)
     sum++;
```

I am very lost on this one. Not sure how does the if statement affects the loop.

Thank you for the help head of time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is in fact `O(n^5)`.  The `sum++` line is executed 1^4 times, then 2^4 times, then 3^4, and so on.  The sum of powers-of-`k` has a term in `n^(k+1)` (see e.g. [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhabers_formula)), so in this case `n^5`.

For the second one, the way to think about it is that the inner loop only executes when `j` is a multiple of `i`.  So the second loop may as well be written `for (j = 1; j < i * i; j+=i)`.  But this is the same as `for (j = 1; j < i; j++)`.  So we now have a sequence of cubes, rather than powers-of-4.  The highest term is therefore `n^4`.

Comment: Are you sure it's O(n^4)?  I'm pretty sure it's O(n^5), but I'm not going to mark you down until I'm sure.

Comment: @Taslem: Yes.  The inner loop iterates `i*i*i` times for each value of `i`.

Comment: @Taslem: This is embarrassing!  I misread the inner loop as iterating up to `i`, not `j`.  So you are in fact correct, and I am in fact incorrect.  Updating my answer accordingly.  Many apologies.  (If you perform a dummy edit to your answer, I can remove the downvote).

Comment: Please pardon me, a what, exactly? If you mean change it, I have, to derive the second answer.

Comment: @Taslem: A "dummy edit"; yes any change at all, even just to add whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure the 1st fragment is actually O(n^5).

Because:

`n` times,

`i^2` times, where `i` is actually half of n (average i for the case, since for each x there is a corresponding n-x that sum to 2n) Which is therefore `n^2 / 4` times. (a times)

Then, a times again,

and when you do:  n*a*a, or n*n*n/4*n*n/4 = n^5 / 16, or O(n^5)

I believe the second is O(4), because:

It's iterated n times.

Then it's iterated n*n times, (literally n*n/4, but not in O notation)

Then only 1/n are let through by the if (I can't remember how I got this)

Then n*n are repeated.

So, n*n*n*n*n/n = n^4.

Comment: -1: A guess isn't a very useful answer.  An incorrect guess is even less useful!

Comment: I never said it was a guess.  I showed how it was gotten.  I've just never been formally taught this, so I don't know if my understanding is correct.  YOU just "guessed" that I'm wrong, even though I showed exactly how I got my answer.

Comment: Downvote rescinded (due to my inability to read the original question properly).

Comment: Anyways... I'm glad I was the first to get it right.  It will be one of my only uprated answers. ;P  Anyways, the best way to derive this sort of this is thinking in terms of how many times each loop is repeated, in terms of those previous.

Answer (score 0):

With a `sum` so handy to compute, you could run these for `n=10`, `n=50`, and so on, and just look which of O(N^2), O(N^3), O(N^4), O(N^6) is a better match. (Note that the index for the inner-most loop *also* runs to n*n...)

Comment: You're not answering the question very well.

Comment: +1: That's exactly what I would do just to check my assumptions about the code.

Answer (score -1):

First off I agree with your assumption for the first scenario. Here is my breakdown for the second.

The If statement will cause the last loop to run only half of the time since an odd value for i*i will only lead to the third inner loop for prime values that i*i can be decomposed into. Bottom line in big-O we ignore constants so I think your looking at O(n^3).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's O(n^5) not 4.